# How much is LEO worth?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, space-industry

I've seen valuations of the space industry at ~$350bn annually.

How much of this is coming from LEO vs MEO/GEO?

Comment: You'd have to figure out how that number is reached. I'll wager it's including things like ULA and SpaceX's corporate valuations (tens of billions, and mostly *on Earth*). It might be including the $100B ISS, too, which is going to skew things. I'd be willing to bet very little of that number is actually physically located in space at all.

Comment: What does valuation annually mean? Where did you find this / how did they explain their numbers? That might help you in trying to figure out an estimate.

Comment: E.g. https://brycetech.com/downloads/SIA_SSIR_2018.pdf shows how the value of the space industry breaks down. Communications and entertainment are quite GEO-heavy, so what is the proportion of this value (design, build, launch, commerce) that comes from LEO? Either annually or as a total value (e.g. ISS has cost $150bn, sum cost over all LEO satellites and include servicing and the value of services provided by commercial satellites).